# How can I set the screen resolution in VirtualBox during a system installation?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, resolution

I want to record the installation process of some operating systems but VirtualBox, without VB guest additions, set the screen resolution to 800x600. So, is there a method to change the resolution during a system installation or to install the guest additions in an installation image?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it would be possible because va drivers are not installed yet neither vmtools to detect screen resolution but check if there are any options to stretch guest.

Comment: Is there a method to installa the drivers inside the system image before the installation?

Comment: That is a very intresting question but it doesn't seem feasible as all firmware are installed during installation.But may be we can edit settings from 800x600 to something else.Never tried it :)

Comment: You can test out scaled mode in view =>scaled mode or scalefactor.They seem to stretch it see if it helps.It doesn't change resolution so u will notice some qualityloss.

Answer (score 0):

U can try running as live cd then changing resolution through settings and then installing without restart or settings will be lost.Good Luck